# Highcharts: multiple CSVs and multiple chart types

Tags: highcharts

I've had success with displaying box plots on Highcharts using a CSV file, but now I'm trying to display another csv file as a scatter plot on the same chart, and I don't know how.

Here's my code that works for the boxplot:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src=  "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get('850_temp2.csv', function(csv) {

var lines = csv.split('\n');
//alert(lines[1]);

 $('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
   type: 'boxplot'
  },
  data: {
   //firstRowAsNames: false,
   //startRow: 2,
   
   //endRow: 15,
   csv: csv
  },
  title: {
   text: '850mb temps'
  },
  xaxis: {
   categories: []
  },
  yaxis: {
   title: {
    text: 'Units'
   }
    

  },
  yAxis: { plotLines: [{
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: 3.5,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<b>Crater Lake</b>'
         
     }
    
    
   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: 1,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Lake of the Woods</b></h2>'
         
     }

   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: 0,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Siskiyou Summit</b></h2>'
         
     }
   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: -3,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Sexton Pass</b></h2>'
         
     }

   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: -5,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Medford</b></h2>'
         
     }


  }] 


      


  }


  
  

 });
 });
});



//$('#container').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(options));

//options.data.switchRowsAndColumns = !options.data.switchRowsAndColumns;








</script>


</head>

<body>


<div id = "container" style="width:1100px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's my code I'm trying to use to display the 2nd CSV file.  I've looked all over, and I can't find something that addresses this.  Here are the csv files.

850_temp2.csv

```
hour,one,two,three,four,five
0,3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 2.0, 5.0
6,2, -1.0, 0.0, -3.0, 2.0 
12,4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 
18,13.0, 12.0, 11.0, 10.0, 10.0 
24,13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 11.0, 6.0 
30,8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 11.0
```

and 
precp.csv

```
hour,one,two,three,four,five
0,0.0, 0.4, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4
6,0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7
12,0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03
18,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.02
24,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
30,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

Thanks for any help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src=  "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get('850_temp2.csv', function(csv) {

 $.get('precp.csv', function(csv2) {

var lines = csv2.split('\n');
alert(lines[1]);
 
 $('#container').highcharts({
 
 
   

  
  
  yAxis: { plotLines: [{
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: 3.5,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<b>Crater Lake</b>'
         
     }
    
    
   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: 1,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Lake of the Woods</b></h2>'
         
     }

   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: 0,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Siskiyou Summit</b></h2>'
         
     }
   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: -3,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Sexton Pass</b></h2>'
         
     }

   }, {
    color: 'darkblue',
    width: 2,
    value: -5,
    zIndex: 100,
    label: {
     text: '<h2><b>Medford</b></h2>'
         
     }


   }]
   }, //y axis close 

   series: [{
   type: 'line',
   name: 'pcpn',
   data: csv2
   },{
   type: 'boxplot',
   name: '850mbT',
   data: csv
   }]
   
      
 

  

  




  
 


 

 }); //highcharts container close
 }); //precip csv close
 }); //850temp csv close

}); //document ready close








//$('#container').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(options));

//options.data.switchRowsAndColumns = !options.data.switchRowsAndColumns;








</script>


</head>

<body>


<div id = "container" style="width:1100px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Essentially, I want to plot these two chart types, but on the same chart.  I'll of course need to add a second y axis that applies to the scatter plot values.

[image: first chart]
[image: second chart]

Comment: Can you paste your csv files sample? Without it the issue cannot be reproduced. If you want multiple series and you want to use data module - you should still load csv as in your first example, but split series array into to objects. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nrm7bjgq/)

Comment: Thanks morganfree.  I added the csv files so hope that helps.  In your example you shared, I don't see exactly how to call the different datasets.  And that's really the problem I think I'm having with my script.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can parse your second csv file on your own and then set it as a second series. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/r5xjw6te/) I am not sure how you want to plot scatter based on your csv file - but all you need to do is parsing it and setting it to data in the second series.

Comment: Morganfree.  I've attached the plots I want (but want them on the same chart), so I want multiple points (entire row) per time period for the scatter plot.  Is there a way I can just get highcharts to read in my file like it does on the chart above?  I'm not having to parse at all on that.  Thanks again for any help.  I'm trying to find the easiest way to plot the two datasets as different chart types...on the same plot.  I think once I can do that, I can figure out the second y axis to apply to the scatter plot values.

Comment: Parse the csv files manually. From the pictures I can see that you need 6 series - see how you can do it http://jsfiddle.net/r5xjw6te/1/ If you need more axes then add a new and match it with the specific series.

Comment: Thanks Morganfree.  I manually parsed the files and it worked great.